Open Specific Url in App or browser when nfc is tap in flutter
I am trying to write the nfc in which i am writing a url , and when the NFC is tap (my app is closed) it should show me whether i want it to open in app or browser.
I tried to modifify the AndroidManifest.xml
 <data android:scheme="https" android:host="https://abc.link/" />
i tried the firbase dyanmic link it just open the app

In Android you can use "Android application records" (https://developer.android.com/develop/connectivity/nfc/nfc#aar); if they are detected the application with the given package name will open. If an app with this package name is not available on the smartphone Android will open the "Google Play Store" to downlod this app.
